# How to dump selected PostgreSQL data from one database to other databse

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have three tables with foreign key relationship with each other.

The table school will be uploaded manually. A student will login to the website and check their marks

The entire data is to be uploaded to another new database of different instance

The Login Id(stud_id) of the student in DB1 is 10 and Login Id(stud_id) of the student in DB2 is 1 in another instance.

For retaining the data of student_marks table, I intend to do the following steps,

```
1. Dump student_marks table from DB1
2. Copy it to DB2
```

> NOTE: stud_id would be different for both the databases

Is there any way to do the above.

Refer the table below,

**school:**

```
 id  | name| place 
-----+-------------
 1 |  sch1  | test
```

**student:**

```
id  | school_id| stud_name 
-----+-------------
 1   |  1       | stud1
```

**student_marks:**

```
 id  | stud_id| subj1 | subj2
-----+-----------------------
 1   |  1    | 30      | 30
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You speak of `Login Id`, but I only see `id` and `stud_id` in your tables. Please be unambiguous. (`CREATE TABLE` statements are always best to be clear.) You also need to provide *some* information how to translate the ID between DBs reliably. And *always* disclose your version(s) of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

First Disable the foreign key constraint, then dump the data and after that again enable the foreign key constraint or you can put foreign key constraint after migrating the data.

Comment: If I set the foreign key after taking a dump, the stud_id in the student_marks table and id in the student table will still be different. How can I able to fetch the record by using the stud_id

Comment: Is the Id column set to auto increment in both the tables? if so, then just migrate the data first and after that make the column as auto increment. If this is not the case then please share your schema.

Comment: Won't there be any read, write permission issue since migrating the data from one database of an instance to another database of another instance

Comment: You can try this way, if you are the admin of the databases then there should not be any problem.